# Why derived class exception could be caught by base class catch clause.

Tags: c++, exception

I've tried following code on Xcode

```
#include <iostream>


/*Exceptions*/
struct A {
    A( int value ) : m_value( value ) {}
    int m_value;
};

struct B : A {
    B( int value ) : A( value ) {}
};
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

/*Exceptions End*/

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    try {
        try {
            throw B( 5 );
        }

        catch ( A a ) {
            a.m_value *= 2;
        }
        catch ( B b ) {
            b.m_value -= 2;
            throw b;
        }

    }
    catch ( A a ) {
        std::cout << a.m_value;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The exception type thrown in here is B, but `catch( A a )` caught B.

I have some thought about this, but don't know if it's correct. I think it's because the copy constructor of A accepts `const A&` which can match B type objects, and copy constructor implicitly convert the datatype from B to A. To confirm this, I added copy constructor for `struct A` :

```
A( const A& other ) : m_value( other.m_value ) {
        std::cout << "hello\n";
}
```

This do output hello while executing `catch( A a )`, but when I defined the copy constructor explicit, like this:

```
explicit A( const A& other ) : m_value( other.m_value ) {
        std::cout << "hello\n";
}
```

The compiler yelled "no matching constructor for initialization of 'A'".

I don't know why. Why didn't it just jump to `catch( B b )` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact issue is covered in [[except.handle]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#4):

> The handlers for a try block are tried in order of appearance. That makes it possible to write handlers that
>   can never be executed, for example **by placing a handler for a derived class after a handler for a corresponding
>   base class.**

If you compiled with warnings enabled, that would also become clear:

```
main.cpp:28:9: warning: exception of type 'B' will be caught
         catch ( B b ) {
         ^
main.cpp:24:9: warning:    by earlier handler for 'A'
         catch ( A a ) {
         ^
```

So yes, what ends up happening is once `B` is thrown, we just go down the list of handlers one by one. Can we catch by `A`? Yes we can! A `B` is convertible to `A`.

Now, when you make `A`'s copy constructor, something interesting happens. You can't implicitly convert a `B` to an `A`, but that's not what the exception logic handling does. It simply checks the types. According to [[except.handle]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#3):

> A *handler* is a match for an exception object of type `E` if
>   — [...]
>   — the handler is of type *cv* `T` or *cv* `T&` and `T` is an unambiguous public base class of `E`, or
>   — [...]

In our case, `A` is an unambiguous public base class of `B` and the handler is of type `A`, so the handler matches. Full stop. Now, turns out we can't actually *use* the handler, so the code is ill-formed.

Comment: very straightforward! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because `catch (A ...)` came first. This is a misfeature of C++. Ideally it would have given you a compilation error for `catch` blocks out of order, or at least for unreachable code. Put `catch (B ...)` first.

Comment: The problem is, if I define the copy constructor as explicit, it won't compile.

Comment: You should catch by reference: `catch (A&...)`, and similarly for B. No reason to catch exceptions by value. Const reference if possible.

Comment: I know, but this is from an interview question. And even if by reference, it still pass by value, because of unwinding

Comment: Sorry, my C++ knowledge predates `explicit`.